# Automatic Reinitialisation in PHP

Tags: php, yii2

I'm writing a simple Game Page.

In my Controller, the method looks like:

```
ppublic function actionGame143(){

    $model = new Game143();
    $level = 1;
    $numEx = 10;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->verifyAnswers($numEx);
        return $this->render('Game143-confirm', ['model' => $model]);
    } else {
        $model->initGame($level, $numEx);
        return $this->render('Game143', ['model' => $model]);
    }

}
```

So `$numEx` is the maximum of level that can be played, and `level` is the starting one.

In my model I save both of them with `initGame($level, $numEx)`:

```
public function initGame($level, $numEx) {
    $this->maxLevel = $numEx; // normally 10
    $this->thisLevel = $level; //normally 1
```

So why do I need to give `verifyAnswer()` again the `$numEx`? If I don´t, the variable is set to `NULL` or whatever I define in the model with the initialization?
Normally it should be saved even as `$thisLevel`?

In my view-class i just do a for-loop with maximum of this variable, until this it works fine:

```
for($model->thisLevel = 1; $model->thisLevel <= $model->maxLevel; $model->thisLevel++) {...}
```

At the End I´m submitting with a button.`$out .= Html::submitButton('Korrigieren', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);`

Don´t know why it is set to the `NULL` value or the initialized one?

Because of an Interface with other programmer I can´t give the `verifyAnswer()` my `$numEx` again.

I´m working with yii2. If I set the value to `required` i cant even submit.